# expected buffer object error on string.translate - python 2.6

Tags: python, string, translate

I´d appreciate some help for a python novice, I´m trying to delete some characters from a string, like this, for example:

```
string1 = "100.000"
deleteList = [",", "."]
string1.translate(None, deleteList)

 print string1
```

but I get a `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Why do I get this error, which argument does it refer to? and where can i find help on this.
I'm using python 2.6 on windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docs for `string.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate) says

```
S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
```

which suggests that `deletechars` should be a string of characters, instead of a list of characters:

```
string1 = "100.000"
string1=string1.translate(None, ',.')
print (string1)
# 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get reffers to your `deleteList` variable, it should be a string. If you really need to store the chars in a list, you could do this:

```
string1.translate(None, ''.join(deleteList))
```