# TypeError: expected a character buffer object while translating

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, dictionary

I am working on a project that uses an sqlite3 database to store some of the data.

My search function uses the SQL statement: `'''SELECT text FROM snippets WHERE title=?''', (whichName,)` and as my code was, `whichName` came in as a dictionary, which garnered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snippets.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "snippets.py", line 24, in main
    get_value_from_name(response)
  File "snippets.py", line 58, in get_value_from_name
    (whichName,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Thus, I figured I needed to pass it as a string, so I just did `name = str(response)` to convert it to a string, but here is where the problem began. It gave me this:

```
[u'TEST'] <--- What is returned by the conversion to a string
None      <--- What is returned by the search function
```

when I converted the dictionary to a string. The search function then returned `None` because it was being passed `[u'TEST']` instead of `TEST` like it should have been. So, I added some translation code:

```
    translation_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '(),'), None)
    # Above code creates a table with the mapped characters

    name = str(response)

    name = name.translate(translation_table)
```

This is where my current problem is. It is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snippets.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "snippets.py", line 20, in main
    name = name.translate(translation_table)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I looked at these questions:

- [Python TypeError: expected a character buffer object, personal misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385419/python-typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-personal-misunderstanding) - not applicable to my problem
- [expected buffer object error on string.translate - python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002206/expected-buffer-object-error-on-string-translate-python-2-6) - also not applicable, as my translation table is created from a string not a dictionary
- [Getting error "expected character buffer object" and I don't know why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416753/getting-error-expected-character-buffer-object-and-i-dont-know-why) - also not applicable because he is trying to do it at an index. I'm trying to do it like it should, finding/replacing throughout the entire string.

but none are applicable to my issue (as far as I can see.)

Does anyone know what is causing the Type Error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I ran the code in Python 3.3.2+ and it works find (albeit a few minor tweaks to the translation table)

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time. I will mark this as answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @culix Absolutely no idea. This project was a while ago, so I don't remember much from it anyways. Sorry :(